# How to redirect with url rewrite in web.config?

Tags: c#, iis, web-config

I am trying to add url rewrite rule to my *.json in root folder of website.

> to check header for authentication and if no header , it redirects.

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.json)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_X_Requested_With}" pattern="com.example.app" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/error.json" />
</rule>
```

But it applies to all json also inside sub folders. how  can I select only for *.json in root folder? Thanks

Comment: I found this article about your post. I hope help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module